# Oozie Cordinator input data event is not working : unformatted function error

Tags: oozie

I am trying run a coordinator job in oozie through ambari gui.. but am getting below exception when i create a dataset input event...

ACTION[-] Exception occurred:Unformatted function :2019-11-02T18:10Z Making the job failed

I am giving start and end time in gui...

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.5" end="2019-11-01T18:20Z" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" name="ETLTest2" start="2019-11-01T18:15Z" timezone="GMT-05:00">
    <datasets>
        <dataset frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="2019-11-01T18:15Z" name="ETL_MDM" timezone="GMT-06:00">
            <uri-template>hdfs://devnamesvccluster/user/sparkcronsvc/edm_ucsys/ingestion/</uri-template>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>
    <input-events>
        <data-in dataset="ETL_MDM" name="ETL_Check_Sqoop">
            <start-instance>2019-11-02T18:10Z</start-instance>
            <end-instance>2019-11-01T18:30Z</end-instance>
        </data-in>
    </input-events>
    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>/user/spid/edm_tab/full/workflow_etl2.xml</app-path>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>`

Let me know if i missing something...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `${coord:current(n)}` or `${coord:latest(n)}` in the data set instances instead of giving specific times. I recommend looking up the book A*pache Oozie* by Mohammad Kamrul Islam and Aravind Srinivasan, it has a good explanation of these data trigger concepts which can be difficult to grasp.

or the official docs for the same:
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.1._coord:currentint_n_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets

An example of how your input event should look:

```
<input-events>
    <data-in name="event_input1" dataset="ds_input1">
        <start-instance>${coord:current(-4)}</start-instance>
        <end-instance>${coord:current(-1)}</end-instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

or

```
<input-events>
    <data-in name="event_input1" dataset="ds_input1">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

You also may want to templatize your uri-template according to how you are partitioning your data:

```
<uri-template>
       hdfs://bar:8020/app/logs/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/data
</uri-template>
```